# How to enable curl_init function without using php.ini?

Tags: curl, php

My problem is right now I am using free hosting and can't access the php.ini file, My free hosting servers shows that cURL is enabled but in [disable functions] they disabled the curl_init() and fsockopen() functoins.
***This means that curl is enabled but the function ( curl_init() and fsockopen() ) is disabled, and I don't have any access to edit the PHP.ini file. Is there any way to enable curl_init() function because I need to use it.*** 
Thanks in advance,
Ramzy Virani.

Comment: Contact your host and ask them to change this, or change your hosting provider

Comment: Free hosts are less likely to change configurations for you, however. Since you can get shared hosting for the price of a cafe coffee per month, perhaps upgrade to a paid account?

Comment: No you can't, you can try file_get_contents maybe it's enable.